# Devise is installed but no methods are found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubymine

I installed Ruby 1.9.3 then Rails 3 then RubyMine 5.4.
I followed the installation guide to install Devise 3.

devise:install

devise user

db:migrate

After that I tried to use the any method from Devise, but none is found, like the method `user_signed_in` or `new_user_session_path` etc...

I'm probably missing something very simple...

**Edit: Routes.rb**

```
C:\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:\Ruby193\bin\rake routes
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                   notes GET    /notes(.:format)               notes#index
                         POST   /notes(.:format)               notes#create
                new_note GET    /notes/new(.:format)           notes#new
               edit_note GET    /notes/:id/edit(.:format)      notes#edit
                    note GET    /notes/:id(.:format)           notes#show
                         PUT    /notes/:id(.:format)           notes#update
                         DELETE /notes/:id(.:format)           notes#destroy
                    root        /                              notes#index

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Edit2:**
Well, turns up it is RubyMine. It just won't recognize any Devise functions for some reason...
Although it showing me errors, the app seems to be functional.

Comment: Maybe you forget to restart server? Also make sure that you have something like `devise_for :users` in config/routes.rb and something like `devise :database_authenticatable #, etc` in models/user.rb

Comment: No..Everything there...

Comment: And you required the 'devise' gem (in Gemfile or otherwise)?

Comment: could you execute 'rake routes' and show the result?

Comment: I do require the gem file.

Comment: have you added the devise settings to your User model?

Comment: I find that rails gets confused sometimes, and I have to kill the "rails server" command and start again.

Comment: Haven you run `bundle install` if you're using bundler?

Comment: Yep.. I did that all... Iv'e even created a virtual machine and installed all from scratch. Still same problem.

Comment: Check out Edit2. Anyone has a clue why this is happening?

Comment: I don't know what it is. so probably not:)

Comment: @Igor which errors is it showing you in edit 2?

Comment: For example, if I'm hovering my mouse over 'user_signed_in?' in the application layout, it shows me: "cannot find 'user_signed_in?'. But it's ok on runtime..